# Balanced graph partitioning for d regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In this setting, you are given a $d$-regular graph $ G=(V,E) $ with $|V| = (d+1) \cdot L$ for some $L > 1$. Is it true that there is some partition of the graph into $d +1$ sets of vertices $V_1, \ldots, V_{d+1}$ of size $L$ such that the cut between each two sets $CUT(V_i, V_j)$, is lower or equal to $L$?

I believe that I can prove this, but perhaps there is something in the literature that I can draw on before I commit to finding the proof. I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Vertex or edge cut?

Comment: Thanks @AnotherUser I will remedy this post.

Comment: @AlmaArjuna edge cut.

Comment: If you do figure out a proof, please let me know.